# SQL Case statement subselect within a grouped by subselect

Tags: sql, db2, case, subquery

I can't figure out how to modify my query to use the newest date between information.infoDate and otherDates.auxDate.

```
SELECT state, COUNT(type) as EQUIPMENT, 
       (SELECT COUNT(type) 
        FROM information a 
        WHERE a.state = b.state 
              AND storedprocedures.to_date(infoDate) < (SELECT current date - 5 days 
                                                        FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) 
        GROUP BY state) as IDLE,
        ROUND((SELECT COUNT(type) 
               FROM information a 
               WHERE a.state = b.state 
                     AND storedprocedures.to_date(infoDate) < (SELECT current date - 5 days 
                                                               FROM sysibm.sysdummy1)
               GROUP BY state) / CAST(COUNT(type) as float) * 100, 1) as percent
FROM information b
JOIN validStates 
  ON state = vstate
LEFT JOIN otherDates 
  ON typeid = auxtypeid
WHERE state <> '***'
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state
```

I've tried the using the following statement various ways instead of infoDate, but I can't get the query to run. Is there a better way to use the newest of the two dates?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN auxDate > infoDate 
            THEN auxDate 
            ELSE infoDate END AS activityDate 
FROM information 
LEFT JOIN otherDates 
       ON typeid = auxtypeid
```

Comment: Could we perhaps get some sample starting data/desired result output?  Which version/platform of DB2?  And is there a 'reflexive' `from_date` function into whatever your destination format is (why isn't stored in a date/time/timestamp type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT state,
COUNT (type) as EQUIPMENT, 
(SELECT COUNT(type) FROM information a LEFT JOIN otherDates on typeid=auxtypeid WHERE a.state=b.state AND (CASE WHEN otherDate > infoDate THEN storedprocedures.dec_to_date(otherDate) ELSE storedprocedures.dec_to_date(infoDate) END) <= (select current date - 5 days from sysibm.sysdummy1) GROUP BY state) as IDLE,
ROUND((SELECT COUNT(type) FROM information a WHERE a.state=b.state AND (CASE WHEN otherDate > infoDate THEN storedprocedures.dec_to_date(otherDate) ELSE storedprocedures.dec_to_date(infoDate) END) < (select current date - 5 days from sysibm.sysdummy1) GROUP BY state)/ CAST(COUNT(type) as float)*100,1) as percent
FROM information b
JOIN validStates ON state=vstate
LEFT JOIN otherDates ON typeid=auxtypeid
WHERE state<>'***'
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE statement is the best way to choose the most recent value of 2 fields.  Why isn't the query running?

Once you add the CASE Statement... make sure you also add the CASE statement to the GROUP BY part of the query as well.

Oh,...   and before you get headaches down the road - you might want to consider *not* making fields with reserved keywords such as state, type,  etc.

EDIT:  Ooops I didnt see the tag of DB2

Comment: So if you were to insert that case statement where infoDate is how would you group by the case statement? I can't group by activityDate.

Comment: If you can reply w/ the SQL with your case statement that fails, perhaps I can help.

I didn't see DB2 at first.  In MS SQL you need to group by the CASE statement... in DB2 perhaps you can simply GROUP BY the alias of the case statement... like GROUP BY activityDate

Answer (score 0):

You may have a better time doing something like the following (until I know more about your table structure/data):

```
WITH Raw as (SELECT a.state, 
                    MAX(a.infoDate, COALESCE(c.auxDate, '0001-01-01')) as activityDate
             FROM information a
             JOIN validStates b
               ON b.vstate = a.state
             LEFT JOIN otherDates c
                    ON typeId = auxtypeid
             WHERE a.state <> '***'),
     Total as (SELECT state, COUNT(*) as count
               FROM Raw
               GROUP BY state),
     Idle as (SELECT state, COUNT(*) as count
              FROM Raw
              WHERE storedprocedures.to_date(activityDate) < (CURRENT_DATE - 5 DAYS)
              GROUP BY state)
SELECT a.state, a.count as EQUIPMENT, b.count as IDLE, 
       ROUND((100.0 * b.count) / a.count, 1) as percent
FROM Total a
LEFT JOIN Idle b
       ON b.state = a.state
ORDER BY a.state
```

... Which'll probably run faster, too.

Please note that, due to the use of `LEFT JOIN`s, `IDLE` and `percent` may be null if the given `state` has no 'idle' types.